meaning of ''pull'' in ''each force causes the lever to pull on the shaft in a different way.''
a force is applied to the end of a lever [Like the picture below], which is attached to a shaft at O (The axis of the shaft is perpendicular to the plane)

The force applied to the lever at point A can have different directions, it can be to the right or downward or oblique. the book says:

although each force
tends to rotate the shaft in the same direction, each causes the lever to
pull on the shaft in a different way.

the question is: What is the meaning of the verb ''pull'' here? Does the book mean that the lever rotates the axis in the direction of force?


... *the lever rotates the axis in the direction of force

Pull has the usual meaning; it describes the action of the force on the lever. The rotation, however, isn't in the direction of the force; it's in the direction caused by the moment of the force.  This would be rotational, unlike the direction of the force.
BBC explains turning effect:

A force may cause an object to turn about a
pivot.


The turning effect of a force is called the moment of the force.


Moments act about a pivot in a clockwise or anticlockwise direction.

